# Nginx looking for files instead of URI when proxying

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

I'm trying to setup nginx as reverse proxy.
When I using just this simple config, all works well.

```
location / {
    proxy_pass https://domain.name; 
    proxy_ssl_server_name on;
}
```

But in my case I have a legacy API and a lot of conditions, and when I using more complex prefix, regex or exact match in case, when my URI looks like this one:

```
/v1/Server.ashx?parameter=value
```

nginx looking for file Server.ashx in default root folder "/usr/share/nginx/html/v1/Server.ashx" instead of proxying, and returns 404.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: The `location` block in your question will not do that. You need to look at the entire `server` block. Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to view the entire configuration across all included files.

Comment: Now I use simple config file:
`events {}`
`http {`
        `include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;`
        `server{`
                `listen 8111;`
                `server_name 192.168.137.43;`
                `location = /v1/Server.ashx?parameter=value {`
                        `proxy_pass https://domain.name;`
                        `proxy_ssl_server_name on;`
                `}`
        `}`
`}`

`# configuration file /etc/nginx/mime.types:`

`types {`
    `...`
`}`
Should I add some directive to server context?

Comment: You cannot test the query string using `location`. The most you can check is `location = /v1/Server.ashx`.

Comment: Thank You, [Richard Smith](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4862445/richard-smith)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this approach helped.
Open for any other advices.

```
server{
    listen 8111;
    server_name 192.168.137.43;
    
    location /v1/Server.ashx {
        error_page 418 = @specificpage;
        error_page 419 = @websocket;
        if ($query_string = "parameter=value") {
            return 418;
        }
        if ($query_string = "") {
            return 419;
        }
        if ($query_string = "otherparameter=othervalue") {
            return 419;
        }
        proxy_pass https://domain.name;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    }
    
    location / {
        error_page 419 = @websocket;
        if ($request_uri = "/v2") {
            return 419;
        }
        if ($request_uri = "/v2?parameter=value") {
            return 419;
        }
        proxy_pass https://domain.name;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    }
    
    location @specificpage {
        proxy_pass https://other.domain.name;
        proxy_ssl_server_name on;
    }
    
    location @websocket {
        proxy_pass http://domain.name;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
    }
}
```